# I made a simple socket in C++ with winsock2 and I put the recv function into a variable and it's giving some weird symbols

Tags: c++, websocket, winsock2

This is my code:

```
 #include "CLIENT.h"

int main() {
    //Locals
    long SUCCESSFUL;
    WSAData WinSockData;
    WORD DLLVersion;
    DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2,1);
    SUCCESSFUL = WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &WinSockData);

    string RESPONSE;
    string CONVERTER;
    char MESSAGE[200];

    SOCKADDR_IN ADDRESS;

    SOCKET sock;
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);

    ADDRESS.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("173.194.219.93");
    ADDRESS.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ADDRESS.sin_port = htons(443);

    cout << "\n\tCLIENT: Do you want to connect to this SERVER? (Y/N)" << endl;
    cin >> RESPONSE;

    RESPONSE[0] = tolower(RESPONSE[0]);

    if(RESPONSE == "n") {
        cout << "\n\tOK. Quitting." << endl;
    }
    else if(RESPONSE == "y") {
        connect(sock, (SOCKADDR*)&ADDRESS, sizeof(ADDRESS));

        SUCCESSFUL = recv(sock, MESSAGE, sizeof(MESSAGE), MSG_PEEK);

        CONVERTER = MESSAGE;

        cout << "\n\tMessage from SERVER:\n\n\t" << CONVERTER << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "That was an inappropriate RESPONSE!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "\n\n\tMSG_PEEK'd data: " << SUCCESSFUL << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

And here's what it gives me: 
"¬◄G" Minus the quotes of course. 
I have no idea what it's suppose to be or mean. Is there some kind of conversion I missed or something?
And in the header file I just include winsock2.h, windows.h, iostream, string, and defined SOCK_VERSION2 0x0202

Answer (score 3):

```
    SUCCESSFUL = recv(sock, MESSAGE, sizeof(MESSAGE), MSG_PEEK);

    CONVERTER = MESSAGE;
```

There are two huge problems here:

1. You don't check whether `recv` succeeded, so `CONVERTER` may contain data or garbage.
2. You ignore `SUCCESSFUL`, which holds the number of bytes you've received. So the assignment operation has no idea how much data is in `MESSAGE` or how many bytes to copy.

The basic problem is that you failed to implement any sort of protocol. TCP is a byte-stream protocol, not a message protocol. If you want to implement messages, you have to define and implement a message protocol. You're expecting it to all work by magic.

There's an old programmer's rule -- nobody may write any software that does anything with TCP until they have memorized this phrase and can explain precisely what it means, "TCP is a reliable byte-stream protocol that does not preserve application message boundaries".

Comment: Thank you very much! :) And seeing as how I can't explain that I will get on it.